# problem in getting location in android 4.0 to up in android studio

Tags: java, android, location, android-4.4-kitkat

i want to get user latitude and longtude in Service , i tried in android under 4.4 and all the thins work good but in android 4.4 to up i cant get user location
already i have all permissions and location is enable .

at the end : if anyway is for get location in service , without opening map  please tell me

this is my code:

```
private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
LocationManager locationManager;
 double lattitude, longitude;





     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {




            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    (MyService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)getApplicationContext(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

            } else {
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager. PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

                if (location != null) {
                    double latti = location.getLatitude();
                    double longi = location.getLongitude();
                    lattitude = latti;
                    longitude =longi;



                } else  if (location1 != null) {
                    double latti = location1.getLatitude();
                    double longi = location1.getLongitude();
                    lattitude = latti;
                    longitude =longi;



                } else  if (location2 != null) {
                    double latti = location2.getLatitude();
                    double longi = location2.getLongitude();
                    lattitude = latti;
                    longitude =longi;


                }else{

                    Log.d("Location", "Cant Get Location ");

                }
            }








        //}
    }
```

Comment: What are you seeing that is happening? Is the location null?

Comment: @tomerpacific yes location is null in android 4.4 to up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are  trying to get last known location. But are you sure that device has last known location? I think you have to request location.

Last known location is the location that device last obtained latitude and longitude.

> For testing before calling your app first open internet goto map and
>   then off the internet and open your app then you will get lastKnown
>   location

So last know location is depend on previous location. If the device has no previous location you will not get any lastKnown location. So the `location` will be null.

So you have to request location. `locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates()` for more details you can [visit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)) here.

Comment: i visit that website and use of that code, but it take very time for getting location

Comment: Depend on Device os and hardware. If you are using GPS provider it take time. If you have internet you will get location fast. But remember you have to access location service first.

Comment: First you have to check has any  lastKnown location if not then requestLocation. Requestion location also depend on distance, time